# Getting a value from a dynamic table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii, datatables

I have a table that is created dynamically using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/).

```
foreach ($results as $value)
        {
            echo '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$value->object_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$value->issn.'</td>
                    <td>'.$value->object_publisher_name.'</td>
                    <td>'.$value->remarks.'</td>
                    <td id="chkbutton">'.$form->checkBox($model,"journal_id").'</td>
                    <td style="display:none;">'.$value->object_id.'</td>
                </tr>';
        }
```

I have to get the value (journal_id) from the hidden column when the corresponding check box is checked and then call the DB to get the data with the corresponding ID and fill a drop down list. How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: use javascript and ajax, you didn't try anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Javascript to specify the details of the columns

```
var table = $('#journal_table').DataTable({

        'columnDefs': [
            // These columns not visible. O is first col, 1 is second, 
            { 'visible': false,  'targets': [ 5 ] },...
            { ...other settings...}
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($results as $value)
    {
        echo '
            <tr>
                <td>'.$value->object_name.'</td>
                <td>'.$value->issn.'</td>
                <td>'.$value->object_publisher_name.'</td>
                <td>'.$value->remarks.'</td>
                <td id="chkbutton">'.$form->checkBox($model,"journal_id").'</td>
                <td style="display:none;">'.$value->object_id.'</td>
            </tr>';
    }
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what I would call an answer.

Comment: Well, then @Ilia, will you so kind to elaborate. Your comment suffers the same pain, in that it does not offer Aman  (or me)  any clues as to why the answer is not an answer.